# SpringBoot annotation @Validated

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

Validation is not called for ItemDTO fields.
How do I make the check work for ItemDTO fields?

If I completely remove the ItemDTO section from the request, then NotNull validation will work, but validation is not called for internal ItemDTO fields.

SpringBoot 2.1.9.RELEASE

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/items")
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class ItemController {
        
        private final ItemLimitService itemLimitService;

        @PostMapping(value = "", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
        public ResponseEntity<ItemLimitDTO> create(@Validated(New.class) @RequestBody ItemLimitDTO limitDTO) {
            ItemLimit limit = itemLimitService.create(limitDTO);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(limit);
        }
        
    }

    public class ItemLimitDTO {

        @Null(groups = {New.class})
        @NotNull(groups = {Exist.class})
        private Integer id;

        @PositiveOrZero(groups = {New.class, Exist.class})
        private Integer value;

        @NotNull(groups = {New.class, Exist.class})
        private ItemDTO item;

    }

    public class ItemDTO {

        @Null(groups = {New.class})
        @NotNull(groups = {Exist.class})
        private Integer id;

        @PositiveOrZero(groups = {New.class, Exist.class})
        private Integer value;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to annotate `@Valid` on `ItemDTO` to enable cascade validation which is mentioned by the hibernate validator documentation as follows :

> The validation of object graphs is recursive, i.e. if a reference
> marked for cascaded validation points to an object which itself has
> properties annotated with **@Valid**, these references will be followed up
> by the validation engine as well. The validation engine will ensure
> that no infinite loops occur during cascaded validation, for example
> if two objects hold references to each other.

So change to the following should fix your problem :

```java
public class ItemLimitDTO {

        @Null(groups = {New.class})
        @NotNull(groups = {Exist.class})
        private Integer id;

        @PositiveOrZero(groups = {New.class, Exist.class})
        private Integer value;

        @Valid
        @NotNull(groups = {New.class, Exist.class})
        private ItemDTO item;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, probably still the right option would be to set @Valid to `ItemDTO item` in ItemLimitDTO, so that not only Integer is validated.

Comment: @ThePrototype, oh , i made a silly mistake when copying the codes in my answer. if you see my content in my description, i am intended to mark the  `@Valid` on the ItemDTO field in `ItemLimitDTO` . And that guy @G.Guvenal just stole my answer  as you can find that he replied just several minutes later than me after reading my solution

Comment: That's what confused me, I gave you a point for answering my question, since you wrote it earlier. I was confused by the absence of @Valid over ItemDTO

Comment: @KenChan I don't reply for point.  I didn't stole your answer. I edited my answer when you wrote your answer. So i didn’t see that. Also how can i stole your answer when your answer is not correct.  Doesn't matter point but you can't say thief to me! Please don’t be rude.

Answer (score 1):

try using `@Validated(New.class)` at the level of the method and `@Valid` for the method argument itself:

```
@Validated(New.class)
@PostMapping(...)
public ResponseEntity<ItemLimitDTO> create(@Valid @RequestBody ItemLimitDTO limitDTO) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work.